# ListView has stopped working since adding Slug field to model

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views, slug

In trying to fix one problem I managed to prevent ListView from working. I tried Googling the problem but got thousands of pages of theory and unfortunately no actual guidance.

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/home.html'  
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
```

I added these lines of code to the model which has caused the problem.

```
url= models.SlugField(max_length=500, unique=True, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.url= slugify(self.title)
        super(UserPost, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**models.py**

*Update - I have tried to add a SlugField based on Pedros comment.*

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    content =  models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    url= models.SlugField(max_length=350, unique=True, blank=True)



    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.url= slugify(self.title)
        super(UserPost, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title 

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('article_detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})


class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='comments')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    email = models.EmailField()
    body = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your model name is `Post` so you should use it as `super` argument:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.url= slugify(self.title)
    super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Or if you are using Python 3, you can just leave `super()` without any arguments:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.url= slugify(self.title)
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```